# PostgreSQL moving data from one table to another with conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I looked around a bit but could not find anything I believed could help so I am asking here. I know Microsoft SQL pretty well but not PostgreSQL and upon trying to make my PostgreSQL query I got stuck right away and realised I would have a lot of exercising to do before I can complete my query, hence asking for help here.

So what I need help with is

1. Select a row from table A
2. Extract a column value from 1. and save it as a variable
3. Select all rows from table B into a variable
4. For each row in 3. take that row, modify it, and insert it into table C

The reason for step 1. and 2. is because I need to fetch a value that contains a counter that I need to use for creating id's that I apply to step 4. So first I need to fetch that id, and save the single value in a variable. Then for each row in table B I need to change the id column value with the new and improved id. It would also be appreciated if I could get help with a full declaration of everything from beginning to end. For example I didn't even manage to declare a function that returns a hard coded varchar value...

Thanks

Comment: I see no need for step 1,2 considering your steps 3 and 4. You might be missing an expression of some logic here. All you need to do can be obtained using a `function`. No need for any variables.

Comment: That's not about database flavor... it's all about "logic" and SQL expertise. If you can solve it in SQLServer, you'll can do it in Postgres also... just use "plain" sql.

Comment: Can you post here what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Try to think in plain SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO target
SELECT as_is_col1, as_is_col2,
       mod_col1*10,
       mod_col2||' extra text',
       row_number() OVER () AS rn
  FROM source
 WHERE wanted_col BETWEEN 100 AND 500;
```

[Check the docs.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html)
Of course, number of selected columns and their types should match to the ones of the table you're inserting into.

I am using window function [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) here to iterate over the rows. This eliminates the need for iterations.

Comment: I need to be able to save the value from step 1. in a variable so that I can increment its value with one for each row I select in table B, hence the request for the loop in step 4.

Comment: @Rebam1, you can mimic iteration either with [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) window function, or [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) set returning function. Pick whichever you like more.